# TableView shows a column that doesn't exist

Tags: fxml

I have the following FXML code for a `TableView` with two columns, yet it shows three as you see in the picture. I don't see why it would show three columns, I only specified two... Any tips?

**FXML**

```
<TableView fx:id="table"
           GridPane.columnIndex="1"
           GridPane.rowIndex="0">
    <columns>
        <TableColumn fx:id="timeColumn" text="time"/>
        <TableColumn fx:id="angleColumn" text="angle"/>
    </columns>

</TableView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to make the columns resize with the size of the table. Simply added this to the FXML.

```
<columnResizePolicy>           
    <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
</columnResizePolicy>
```